# How do I update a "global" variable inside a while loop?

Tags: bash

So I have this If statement that checks what the exit code of the script is:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    wasSuccessful=true;
fi
```

In other languages, I would do something like:

```
while wasSuccessful == false
```

And then the loop would keep running until the exit code was true. (I plan to implement a loop counter as well for too many failed attempts, but that's a different problem to solve)

I think I need a here-string, but I'm not exactly sure how that would look. Here's a rough outline of my code right now, in Bash:

```
wasSuccessful=false

while [ "$wasSuccessful" = "false" ]
do

#Bunch of code here, then the check for exit code

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    wasSuccessful=true;
fi

done
```

Any suggestions on how to do something like this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Your code seems OK.  What is the problem you are facing?  All variables in Bash are global unless declared as local inside a function.

Comment: I thought the while loop executed in a subshell, so changes I make to variables are saved only to that session scope. Is that not correct?

Comment: @iMatthewCM the `while loop` not executed in subshell, unless you put them inside quote `(commands)`.

Comment: The confusion is probably that often people will pipe input into a `while` loop, and things involved in a pipeline are run in subshells.  So if you did, say, `getent passwd user_prefix | while read -r ent; do...` then that loop would be in a subshell, as written yours would not create a subshell

Comment: Oh, that's very helpful, thank you @EricRenouf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is how to exit `while loop` when the latest command execute successfully inside `while loop`?

You don't need a `global variable` to check. Just check the status of previous command and `break` it if succeed.

```
while true
do
    # a bunch of code here
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && break
done
```

Comment: The opposite of that I think. If the exit code is anything other than 0, I need to keep looping.

Comment: Yes, the code above will keep your loop running if the exit code is not 0.

Comment: Well...that's pretty awesome. Thank you very much! That's much more elegant than what I was doing. I'll give that a shot when I get back to work tomorrow (just leaving now) and if it works I'll accept the answer :)